# How to format data exported from BinDiff?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, tool-bindiff

I am using BinDiff 4.0 as a plug-in for IDA Pro 6.5. I know that it is possible to save the results as a `.BinDiff` file, however is there a way I can format this into a more easily accessible file type? I have been searching for a solution for several days and so far the two best solutions I have discovered are to:

1. Copy and paste the matched functions window (this is simply too inefficient for what I am looking for).
2. Export the data as a `.BinDiff` and then access through an SQL database manager and try to export from there. However it seems to change the data to incorrect values and not what I am looking for. (I want the exact information from the matched functions window).

**Additional Information**: I know that BinDiff 3.x had a `save_to_log` function which (I think) did what I am looking for, and saves the information in the matched function window to a `.txt` file. I have tried contacting both Zynamics support, and Google/Zynamics support with no reply.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if a separate email got lost somewhere, but the .BinDiff file that BinDiff saves is in fact a sqlite3 database -- so the easiest way to get the
results would be to use sqlite to dump the results.